# Error [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `Student` model once compiled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm making a Next.js app and I'm using MongoDB to store a user. The first time I call the API, it works, but when I call it again, I get an error stating:
`` error Error [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `Student` model once compiled. ``

As a bit of a background, I defined the model in a different file and use export default to use it as a global variable.

Here is my code:
**/api/auth/index.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import Student from "../../../models/Student";
import Organization from "../../../models/Organization";

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const student = Student.findOne({ email: "test" });

    if (!student) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Email not found" });
    } else {
      res.status(201).json(student);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "URL Not Found" });
  }
};
```

**/models/Student.ts**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },

  school: { type: String },
  zip: { type: Number, required: true },
  grade: { type: Number },
  profPic: { type: String },
  description: { type: String },
  areas: [{ type: String }],
  followers: [{ type: String }],
  following: [{ type: String }],
});

export default mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "return" keyword in your responses.